# C++ trouble setting enum field in structure constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, enums

I'm trying to set an enum in a structure constructor but I can't quite get the syntax correct.  Are there any suggestions?  This is what I have but I keep getting errors.

```
struct Event{
    enum eventType { Arrival, CPUburstCompletion, IOcompletion, TimerExpired }enumField;
    double time; // Defined as time units since the start of the simulation

    Event(eventType e, double theTime): enumField(e), time(theTime){}
};
```

Comment: In the future, it would be helpful if you shared the compiler output (error messages etc.).

Comment: Your code seems OK. Please share compiler output.

Comment: It's saying        
        Invalid redefinition of 'eventType'

Comment: This code compiles just fine on its own. Please share a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse on this.  I got it to compile now as is but there's still a warning on the second line saying "Invalid redefinition of 'eventType'  When I try to use the constructor Listed above and pass the values "Arrival" for eventType and "12" for time, I get the error " - 'Arrival' was not declared in this 
  scope
 - Symbol 'Arrival' could not be 
  resolved"

Comment: @Erk: the code as shown here does not have any errors or warnings. There's something else you haven't shared that's causing your problem. Additionally, your enum is in the scope of the struct, so if you want to use the values outside of the struct, you need to qualify them, e.g. `Event::Arrival`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe...

```
struct Event {
  enum TYPE {
    Arrival,
    CPUBurstCompletion,
    IOCompletion,
    TimerExpired
  };
  double time;  
  TYPE type;  
  Event(Event::TYPE type, double time)
      : type(type),
        time(time) { }
};

int main() {
  Event e(Event::Arrival, 1.0);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried that as well and got "Invalid redefinition of 
 'TYPE'"

Comment: What compiler are you using? I can compile the above code using gcc 4.7.2.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse with MacOSX GCC

Comment: I ran it with this code and it seems to be working.  I'm still getting errors in Eclipse but it runs.  I've never seen eclipse act like this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
struct Event{
    enum eventType { Arrival, CPUburstCompletion, IOcompletion, TimerExpired };

    eventType enumField;


    double time; // Defined as time units since the start of the simulation

    Event(eventType e, double theTime): enumField(e), time(theTime){}
};
```

Comment: I tried that and I get the same error.  "Invalid redefinition of 
 'eventType'"